# Python: Compare information in two text files and write matching info to new file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

Hope to have suggestions for solving this

I have two text files A and B
A=

```
23,34,67,56  
45,66,86,98  
65,113,77,99
```

B=

```
11,34,58,99,109,24  
23,34,67,56,99,98  
55,100,75,45,44,90  
65,113,77,99,114,45
```

What I want is to select all row elements in B where there is a match between a unique key value made from concatenating the first two row elements, and write these lines to a new file C.

Based on the example files A and B;
C=

```
23,34,67,56,99,98  
65,113,77,99,114,45
```

The input files both have typically 100 000 rows
Thank you for assistance

Comment: Homework? Show the example of concatenating.

Comment: @user2659801 What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have CSV files here, so use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read and write these files. Use a set to store the unique keys from A, then use that set to filter rows from B:

```
import csv

with open(A, 'rb') as file_a:
    selected = {tuple(row[:2]) for row in csv.reader(file_a)}

with open(B, 'rb') as file_b, open(C, 'wb') as file_c:
    reader = csv.reader(file_b)
    writer = csv.writer(file_c)
    writer.writerows(row for row in reader if tuple(row[:2]) in selected)
```

Note that sets, like dictionaries, can only store hashable values, so we turn the first two columns of each CSV row into a tuple to fit that requirement.

Comment: Only had to modify  as follows:   writer = csv.writer(file_c)

Comment: :-) Saved me half a day work. Thanks again.